# JS Export HTMLArray to CSV - delimer issue

Tags: javascript, export, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

i have data which i need to export to .csv, for Excel.
I have a function which is working fine but the result file contains all data in first row, in Excel.
Then i need to go to the "Data" tab, then "Text to columns" and pick comma as a delimer.
This is not acceptable.
How can i generate .csv file to avoid this formatting issue ?
I tried \t as a delimer but its not working :/

```
function download_csv_file(data) {  

//define the heading for each row of the data  
var csv = 'Header A, Header B, Header C\n';  
  
//merge the data with CSV  
data.forEach(function(parentRow) {  
    parentRow.childNodes.forEach(function(row) {
        csv += row.text.concat(',');  
    });
    csv += "\n";
});  

//display the created CSV data on the web browser   
document.write(csv);  

 
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');  
hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';  
  
//provide the name for the CSV file to be downloaded  
hiddenElement.download = 'File_name.csv';    
hiddenElement.click();
```

}

thank in advance for all suggestions

Comment: Can you share the format of data that actually you have it in "data" variable?

Comment: In windows, its \r\n. Also you can use papa-parse.js

Comment: @John \r\n and \r is not working also. Each header is in the new line, instead of next column